TWrapMode = TileOriginal repeats edge pixels?
Asking to verify if this behavior is a feature, so that I don't get any nasty surprises in the future. I can't find any documentation on it, but if anyone has any, I'd be grateful.
When I use a bitmap as a fill brush in, for instance, a TRectangle, and set WrapMode to TileOriginal, the edge pixels of the image get repeated. I'm counting on this being a feature, therefore I ask whether it actually is.

Resulting rectangle. The bitmap is just a transparent rectangle with a white border.

Thanks.
